# Partition sizes for Linux total to 50Gb

Tags: partitioning, disk-management

I have decided to dual boot ubuntu on my machine.
I have allocated a free space of 50Gb to ubuntu!.

My Laptop has 8Gb of Ram.

root - 15 gb

swap - 12 gb

home - 23 gb

Is it Okay?

Answer (score 2):

In new installations of Ubuntu 18.04 a swap file is created in the ext4 root partition by default instead of a swap partition. You also don't need a separate home partition. A single 50GB ext4 partition would make the most efficient use of the 50GB of available disk space, and that is also the partitioning scheme that the Ubuntu installer will create by default. 50GB will provide enough disk space to install all the software that you need, but you will not be able to download too many other large files.

Comment: so should i go for default option?

Comment: Go with the default option to make the most efficient use of the 50GB available disk space. Even with 50GB of disk space, you will run out of disk space if you download too many other large files.

Comment: if i'm going to select the default option in ubuntu installer, do i really need to create partition(free space) in windows using windows disk management?

Comment: Everything adjusts automatically if you select the default option in the Ubuntu installer. The only limitation is that the size of the single partition is the maximum size of everything that can be written to that partition.

Comment: but i'll have to create free space first, right?

Comment: You don't have to create anything first. The Ubuntu installer has a graphical interface partitioning screen in which you can move a slider to set the size of the Ubuntu partition.

Answer (score 0):

I personally do more or less as you do.
I prefer keeping my home separate if I can, it facilitates full install when a new version comes out, or if I want to try a new flavour.
I also installed my swap in a another partition, but this was because I wanted to have it on my SATA drive and not on my SSD (my computer has 2 drives).